# MEW iOS App crash on contract deploy

Tags: contract-deployment, myetherwallet, ios

I'm trying to deploy a contract via the UI on http://myetherwallet.com/.

The contract was created with the Remix online IDE and when pasting the bytecode and ABI/Json interface contract pieces, the green check mark lights up meaning they should work.

1. in MEW iOS app, Change network to ROP.
2. Using MEW iOS app, scan QR code to authenticate.
3. Go to deploy contract page.
4. Paste valid bytecode and ABI
5. Change network to Ropsten (myetherwallet.com variety) and the gas automatically updated to to having a balance of 1 ROP.
6. Hit deploy contract.
7. Contact shows as sending - 0 ROP, not sending 1 ROP.
8. Enter password on iOS MEW app, press accept and deploy.
9. App crashed in under 1 second with the following error log (truncated due to character limitations):

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
{"app_name":"MyEtherWallet-iOS","timestamp":"2019-03-10 14:43:16.79 -0400","app_version":"1.0.8","slice_uuid":"95f2be73-3ec4-37d1-8dbb-1eeee186cc17","adam_id":1391097156,"build_version":"19021103","bundleID":"com.myetherwallet.mewconnect","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.1.4 (16D57)","incident_id":"D3FC7CB5-BD63-425F-95EB-973E6E4F0C09","name":"MyEtherWallet-iOS"}
Incident Identifier: D3FC7CB5-BD63-425F-95EB-973E6E4F0C09
CrashReporter Key:   3ec88b803ee3efd56a2254146aaae089f1cae302
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,6
Process:             MyEtherWallet-iOS [18541]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F858193E-2239-46D4-852A-758B65FAEC9F/MyEtherWallet-iOS.app/MyEtherWallet-iOS
Identifier:          com.myetherwallet.mewconnect
Version:             19021103 (1.0.8)
AppStoreTools:       10B63
AppVariant:          1:iPhone10,6:12
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.myetherwallet.mewconnect [2064]


Date/Time:           2019-03-10 14:43:16.6139 -0400
Launch Time:         2019-03-10 14:34:57.9744 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1.4 (16D57)
Baseband Version:    2.02.51
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010074ac30
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [18541]
Triggered by Thread:  11

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208fe7ea4 0x208fd0000 + 97956
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208fe737c 0x208fd0000 + 95100
2   QuartzCore                      0x000000020da01b3c 0x20d91a000 + 949052
3   QuartzCore                      0x000000020d9c5dc4 0x20d91a000 + 703940
4   QuartzCore                      0x000000020d9c61a4 0x20d91a000 + 704932
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000002366b7414 0x235d50000 + 9860116
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000002366b4bb4 0x235d50000 + 9849780
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000002366b4780 0x235d50000 + 9848704
8   UIKitCore                       0x00000002366b67f0 0x235d50000 + 9857008
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000002366b642c 0x235d50000 + 9856044
10  UIKitCore                       0x00000002366b3fb8 0x235d50000 + 9846712
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000002366b4390 0x235d50000 + 9847696
12  UIKitCore                       0x0000000236abfea0 0x235d50000 + 14089888
13  MyEtherWallet-iOS               0x00000001006ca0bc 0x10069c000 + 188604
14  UIKitCore                       0x0000000235f9d15c 0x235d50000 + 2412892
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000023664487c 0x235d50000 + 9390204
16  UIKitCore                       0x0000000236632878 0x235d50000 + 9316472
17  UIKitCore                       0x0000000236661880 0x235d50000 + 9508992
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093ed6bc 0x209341000 + 706236
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093e8350 0x209341000 + 684880
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093e88f0 0x209341000 + 686320
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093e80e0 0x209341000 + 684256
22  GraphicsServices                0x000000020b661584 0x20b656000 + 46468
23  UIKitCore                       0x0000000236638c00 0x235d50000 + 9341952
24  MyEtherWallet-iOS               0x00000001006a75f4 0x10069c000 + 46580
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000208ea6bb4 0x208ea6000 + 2996

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208fe7ea4 0x208fd0000 + 97956
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208fe737c 0x208fd0000 + 95100
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093edad8 0x209341000 + 707288
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093e8974 0x209341000 + 686452
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093e80e0 0x209341000 + 684256
5   Foundation                      0x0000000209dde494 0x209dd6000 + 33940
6   Foundation                      0x0000000209dde340 0x209dd6000 + 33600
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000002367290c4 0x235d50000 + 10326212
8   Foundation                      0x0000000209f1123c 0x209dd6000 + 1290812
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907825c 0x20906d000 + 45660
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002090781bc 0x20906d000 + 45500
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcf4 0x20906d000 + 60660

Thread 2 name:  network_thread 0x0x102409cf0
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208ff3350 0x208fd0000 + 144208
1   WebRTC                          0x0000000101748478 0x10167c000 + 836728
2   WebRTC                          0x000000010173a68c 0x10167c000 + 779916
3   WebRTC                          0x000000010174ee54 0x10167c000 + 863828
4   WebRTC                          0x000000010174ed00 0x10167c000 + 863488
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907825c 0x20906d000 + 45660
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002090781bc 0x20906d000 + 45500
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcf4 0x20906d000 + 60660

Thread 3 name:  worker_thread 0x0x102407aa0
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208ff2f0c 0x208fd0000 + 143116
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000209075410 0x20906d000 + 33808
2   WebRTC                          0x0000000101689194 0x10167c000 + 53652
3   WebRTC                          0x00000001017408ac 0x10167c000 + 805036
4   WebRTC                          0x000000010173a68c 0x10167c000 + 779916
5   WebRTC                          0x000000010174ee54 0x10167c000 + 863828
6   WebRTC                          0x000000010174ed00 0x10167c000 + 863488
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907825c 0x20906d000 + 45660
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002090781bc 0x20906d000 + 45500
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcf4 0x20906d000 + 60660

Thread 4 name:  signaling_thread 0x0x10240e720
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208ff2f0c 0x208fd0000 + 143116
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000209075410 0x20906d000 + 33808
2   WebRTC                          0x0000000101689194 0x10167c000 + 53652
3   WebRTC                          0x00000001017408ac 0x10167c000 + 805036
4   WebRTC                          0x000000010173a68c 0x10167c000 + 779916
5   WebRTC                          0x000000010174ee54 0x10167c000 + 863828
6   WebRTC                          0x000000010174ed00 0x10167c000 + 863488
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907825c 0x20906d000 + 45660
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002090781bc 0x20906d000 + 45500
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcf4 0x20906d000 + 60660

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208fe7ea4 0x208fd0000 + 97956
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208fe737c 0x208fd0000 + 95100
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093edad8 0x209341000 + 707288
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093e8974 0x209341000 + 686452
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093e80e0 0x209341000 + 684256
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000209a0b00c 0x209a09000 + 8204
6   Foundation                      0x0000000209f1123c 0x209dd6000 + 1290812
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907825c 0x20906d000 + 45660
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002090781bc 0x20906d000 + 45500
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcf4 0x20906d000 + 60660

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFStream.LegacyThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208fe7ea4 0x208fd0000 + 97956
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208fe737c 0x208fd0000 + 95100
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093edad8 0x209341000 + 707288
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093e8974 0x209341000 + 686452
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093e80e0 0x209341000 + 684256
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000209401174 0x209341000 + 786804
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907825c 0x20906d000 + 45660
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002090781bc 0x20906d000 + 45500
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcf4 0x20906d000 + 60660

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208ff3350 0x208fd0000 + 144208
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000002093f6928 0x209341000 + 743720
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907825c 0x20906d000 + 45660
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002090781bc 0x20906d000 + 45500
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcf4 0x20906d000 + 60660

Thread 8 name:  SendControllerThread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208ff2f0c 0x208fd0000 + 143116
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000209075410 0x20906d000 + 33808
2   WebRTC                          0x0000000101689164 0x10167c000 + 53604
3   WebRTC                          0x00000001017ece38 0x10167c000 + 1510968
4   WebRTC                          0x0000000101688c2c 0x10167c000 + 52268
5   WebRTC                          0x0000000101688bc8 0x10167c000 + 52168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907825c 0x20906d000 + 45660
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002090781bc 0x20906d000 + 45500
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcf4 0x20906d000 + 60660

Thread 9 name:  SCTP iterator
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208ff2f0c 0x208fd0000 + 143116
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000209075410 0x20906d000 + 33808
2   WebRTC                          0x0000000101918894 0x10167c000 + 2738324
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907825c 0x20906d000 + 45660
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002090781bc 0x20906d000 + 45500
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcf4 0x20906d000 + 60660

Thread 10 name:  SCTP timer
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208ff3350 0x208fd0000 + 144208
1   WebRTC                          0x0000000101918c88 0x10167c000 + 2739336
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907825c 0x20906d000 + 45660
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002090781bc 0x20906d000 + 45500
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcf4 0x20906d000 + 60660

Thread 11 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 11 Crashed:
0   MyEtherWallet-iOS               0x000000010074ac30 0x10069c000 + 715824
1   MyEtherWallet-iOS               0x000000010074acb4 0x10069c000 + 715956
2   MyEtherWallet-iOS               0x00000001006cfa10 0x10069c000 + 211472
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000208e956c8 0x208e35000 + 394952
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000208e96484 0x208e35000 + 398468
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000208e6ca6c 0x208e35000 + 227948
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000208e78aec 0x208e35000 + 277228
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000208e7934c 0x208e35000 + 279372
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907917c 0x20906d000 + 49532
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bcec 0x20906d000 + 60652

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bce8 0x20906d000 + 60648

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020907bce8 0x20906d000 + 60648

Thread 11 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x00000002100fc882   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001020142d0
    x4: 0x0000000101dd6f80   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x000000016f9030e0   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000283962400  x11: 0x000000090000000f
   x12: 0x0000000283962420  x13: 0x000041a1007e0a5d  x14: 0x0000000000000002  x15: 0x000000010076972b
   x16: 0x0000000208647858  x17: 0x0000000100711920  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000028211ba20
   x20: 0xb005c5016c76379d  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x00000001024ecae0  x23: 0x000000028211ba80
   x24: 0x0000000282668eb0  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000003  x27: 0x0000000000000030
   x28: 0x0000000000000020   fp: 0x000000016f902db0   lr: 0x000000010074a670
    sp: 0x000000016f9026c0   pc: 0x000000010074ac30 cpsr: 0x60000000

Binary Images:
0x10069c000 - 0x100787fff MyEtherWallet-iOS arm64  <95f2be733ec437d18dbb1eeee186cc17> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F858193E-2239-46D4-852A-758B65FAEC9F/MyEtherWallet-iOS.app/MyEtherWallet-iOS
0x100810000 - 0x10081bfff RamblerAppDelegateProxy arm64  <f5dc9a1cea0b34e8a0735ac9125e30a7> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F858193E-2239-46D4-852A-758B65FAEC9F/MyEtherWallet-iOS.app/Frameworks/RamblerAppDelegateProxy.framework/RamblerAppDelegateProxy
0x10082c000 - 0x10085ffff AFNetworking arm64  <c327c04e00bd3b2eb9c78e551e4b9c65> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F858193E-2239-46D4-852A-758B65FAEC9F/MyEtherWallet-iOS.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
0x1008b8000 - 0x1008c3fff BEMCheckBox arm64  <a031195b475f350ca019f586a46bb0fa> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F858193E-2239-46D4-852A-758B65FAEC9F/

...
```